# Documentation: list of operators

Tags: rascal

Is there somewhere I can find a list of operators.

If "+", "-", "/", "%", "==", "<=", "<",... and even "<-" are common to most languages, there are some like "::", "| (ADT)", "| (Set)" or "in" (for ADT alternative), which are specific to rascal.

Something like [what can be found here for java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html).

I could not find them in the documentation, which is otherwise really good.

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation of our documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the operators are described here: http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Expressions/Expressions.html#/Rascal/Expressions/Operators/Operators.html

There are some more types of expressions which can also be seen as operators here: http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Expressions/Expressions.html#/Rascal/Expressions/Expressions.html

Comment: Thanks, Jurgen. But operators is a word with many meanings. I was talking about all those keywords that appears as infix in between expressions. Which, in facts, constitute the articulation of the language. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: I understand that it may difficult to provide, due to the MPL nature of Rascal. But it cost nothing to ask.

Comment: I think the operator table on the operator page should have all of the infix operators listed, and some prefix and postfix operators, like transitive closure +. If that table does not answer your question, then I need some more explanation about the question. It could also be that some operators are missing; I'll have a look at that.

Comment: @AlainD we could query the grammar of Rascal itself and give a full list of all literals in the language?

Comment: This is my ground truth source for all things syntactic in Rascal: https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/blob/master/src/org/rascalmpl/library/lang/rascal/syntax/Rascal.rsc